# How can I reject base64 encoded spam email?

Tags: postfix, spam

I just received couple of mails with similar content which were  encoded with base64. Now I want to reject or discard these kind of emails using body check.

Before I had in my body_checks something like this:

```
/Quanzhoucooway/ DISCARD
```

But since the message is encoded that keyword will not be detected.

Here is a base64 encoded message:

```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```

So what is the best practice to block these kind of emails?

Comment: Proper spam filtering that acts on the actual decoded contents of the message?

Comment: Could you be more specific, what kind of mechanism should be used? I'm already using spamassassin and it's doing a great job when it comes to fighting against spam.

Comment: I would MTA-reject them with a error message of "Don't base64 encode message bodies".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't do this with Postfix [`body_check`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#body_checks) but [write a Spamassassin rule](https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/WritingRules) for it, instead. Spamassain decodes the message body before applying its rules. Something like:

```
body     LOCAL_QUANZHOUCOOWAY  /Quanzhoucooway/
score    LOCAL_QUANZHOUCOOWAY  7.0
describe LOCAL_QUANZHOUCOOWAY  Block word Quanzhoucooway
```

These rules belongs to `/etc/mail/spamassassin/local.cf` (or `~/.spamassassin/user_prefs`).

Comment: Will this work even if that keyword is encoded with base64, like that content up there?

Comment: Yes. Someone already edited my answer to clarify this. Thanks to that anonymous person! :)

Answer (score 11):

Technically, you *could* directly filter the base64 encoded data for keywords.  I'm not saying it's a practical or a reasonable thing to do, given the existence of better and simpler alternatives (as described e.g. in Esa's answer above), but it *is* possible.

The trick is to realize that [base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is a deterministic mapping of 3-byte blocks of raw unencoded data into 4-character blocks of base64 characters.  Thus, any time a certain sequence of 3-byte blocks appears in the unencoded data, the same sequence of 4-character blocks will appear in the encoded version.

For example, if you enter the string `Quanzhoucooway` into a [base64 encoder](https://www.google.com/search?q=base64+encoder), you'll get the output `UXVhbnpob3Vjb293YXk=`.  Since the length of the input is not a multiple of 3 bytes, the output contains some [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Output_padding) at the end, but if we drop the final `=` signs and the last actual base64 character `k` (since it also encodes some padding bits), we get the string `UXVhbnpob3Vjb293YX` that is guaranteed to appear in the base64-encoded data whenever the byte triplets `Qua`, `nzh`, `ouc`, `oow` and the partial triplet `ay` appear in the input in that order.

But, of course, the string `Quanzhoucooway` might not start exactly on triplet boundary.  For example, if we encode the string `XQuanzhoucooway` instead, we get the output `WFF1YW56aG91Y29vd2F5`, which looks completely different.  This time, the input length is divisible by three, so there are no padding characters to discard at the end, but we do need to discard the first two characters (`WF`) which each encode some of the bits from the prepended `X` byte, leaving us with `F1YW56aG91Y29vd2F5`.

Finally, base64 encoding `XXQuanzhoucooway` gives the output `WFhRdWFuemhvdWNvb3dheQ==`, which has padding at both ends.  Removing the first three characters `WFh` (which encode the `XX` prefix) and the last three characters `Q==` (which encode the zero bit padding at the end), we're left with the string `RdWFuemhvdWNvb3dhe`.  Thus, we obtain the following three base64-encoded strings:

```
UXVhbnpob3Vjb293YX
F1YW56aG91Y29vd2F5
RdWFuemhvdWNvb3dhe
```

of which (at least) one must appear in the base64 encoded form of any input string containing the word `Quanzhoucooway`.

Of course, if you're unlucky, the base64 encoder may insert a line break in the middle of them, between any two encoded triplets.  (Your example message, for example, has one between `F1YW56` and `aG91Y29vd2F5`.)  Thus, to reliably match these strings with regexps, you'd need something like the following (using PCRE syntax):

```
/UXVh\s*bnpo\s*b3Vj\s*b293\s*YX/ DISCARD
/F1\s*YW56\s*aG91\s*Y29v\s*d2F5/ DISCARD
/R\s*dWFu\s*emhv\s*dWNv\s*b3dh\s*e/ DISCARD
```

Generating these patterns by hand is kind of tedious, but it wouldn't be hard to write a simple script to do it in your favorite programming language, at least as long as it provides a base64 encoder.

If you really wanted, you could even implement case-insensitive matching by base64 encoding both the lowercase and the uppercase version of the keyword and combining them into a regexp that matches any combination of them.  For example, the base64 encoding of `quanzhoucooway` is `cXVhbnpob3Vjb293YXk=` while that of `QUANZHOUCOOWAY` is `UVVBTlpIT1VDT09XQVk=`, so the rule:

```
/[cU][XV]V[hB]\s*[bT][nl]p[oI]\s*[bT][31]V[jD]\s*[bT][20]9[3X]\s*[YQ][XV]/ DISCARD
```

will match the base64 encoded word "Quanzhoucooway" in any case, provided that it begins on a triplet boundary.  Generating the other two corresponding regexps for the shifted versions is left as an exercise. ;)

Alas, doing anything more complicated than simple substring matching like this quickly becomes impractical.  But at least it's a neat trick.  In principle, it could even be useful, if you for some reason could not use SpamAssassin or any other filter that can decode the base64 encoding before filtering.  But if you can do that, instead of using hacks like this, you certainly should.

Comment: Yes, it's *possible*; not so practical, and not something you'd like to do again for every word. +1 for the explanation: while this might not be very useful, it certainly is educating!